# python if - else operator precedence

Tags: python

I came across a very nasty example of the `if` - `else` operator in Python where the code looked good but the result was completely different than expected. Here is a short version:

```
1 + 4 if None else 3  # returns 3
```

Looking at the [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) table in the documentation, it seems that `if` - `else` has almost the lowest precedence.

Is there anything special with `if` - `else` that treats everything on the left side of the `if` as one expression?

Comment: Ironically, your C++ example prints `4` regardless of `+` and `?:`'s relative priority.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?  The reason you see that behavior is that the if/else operator has the lowest precedence (except for lambda).

Comment: I think a parenthesis is what you're looking for, right? Just wrap "(4 if None else 3)" in parenthesis and you're done

Comment: True, my c++ example is rubbish :)

Comment: I actually didn't read the doc carefully either on first look - what you probably missed is "The following table summarizes the operator precedences in Python, from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `None` is always false, so that you always get 3.

`1 + 4` would be the result if you used a true value instead of `None`:

```
1 + 4 if True else 3
```

gives 5.

That's exactly because of low precedence: it is the same as

```
(1 + 4) if ... else 3
```

as - you know - the precedence of `if ... else` is lower than that of `+`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the *order*, not the precedence. Both the `if`...`else` operator in Python and the `?`...`:` operator in c have extremely low precedence (lower than `+` and `-`, anyway).

Python: `result_if_true if conditional else result_if_false`

c: `conditional ? result_if_true : result_if_false`

Consider the order of your example:

```
print 1 + 4 if None else 3
```

is the same as:

```
print (1 + 4) if (None) else (3)
```

which translates to c as:

```
cout << (0) ? (1 + 4) : (3);
```

where `None` is translated to `0` since `None` is a falsey in Python.

To get your c into Python...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = (1 + 0) ? (4) : (3);
    cout << x; // prints 4
    return 0;
}
```

Translates to:

```
x = 4 if 1 + 0 else 3
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
print 1 + (4 if None else 3)
```

Which prints `4`

Answer (score -1):

This is example of conditional expression in python.

It will execute block between IF and ELSE

1. if block is return non zero or TRUE then it will execute left side of IF statement
2. if block is Zero or FALSE or NONE then it will execute right side of ELSE statement

1 + 4 if None else 3
In above line NONE menace FALSE will return so it will execute right side of ELSE block which is 3

Please see below code to understand conditional expression in python

```
a,b=10,1
v="A is less tahn B" if a < b else "A is greater than B"
print(v)
```

#### output --> *A is greater than B*